# C++11 - Keeping track of templated static storage of repeated types

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I'm trying to create a flexible multi-track animation system using only C++11.

So far I have this code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <array>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <map>

template<typename T>
struct AnimationTrack
{
    using map_type = std::map<float, T>;
    map_type keyframes;

    AnimationTrack(std::initializer_list<typename map_type::value_type>&& keyframes) :
        keyframes(std::move(keyframes)) {}
};

template<typename T>
struct AnimationTrackView
{
    AnimationTrack<T>* track;

    AnimationTrackView() : 
        track(nullptr) {}

    AnimationTrackView(AnimationTrack<T>* track) :
        track(track) {}
};

template<typename... TrackTs>
class Animation
{
public:
    Animation(AnimationTrack<TrackTs>&... tracks)
    {
        StoreViews(tracks...);
    }

    template<std::size_t Index>
    auto& GetTrack()
    {
        return GetStorage<std::tuple_element<Index, std::tuple<TrackTs...>>::type>()[this].track;
    }

private:
    template<typename T>
    static auto& GetStorage()
    {
        static std::unordered_map<Animation*, AnimationTrackView<T>> storage;
        return storage;
    }

    template<typename T, typename... Ts>
    void StoreViews(AnimationTrack<T>& current, AnimationTrack<Ts>&... rest)
    {
        auto& storage = GetStorage<T>(); 
        storage.emplace(this, std::addressof(current));
        using expander = int[];
        (void)expander {
            0, (void(GetStorage<Ts>().emplace(this, std::addressof(rest))), 0)...
        };
    }
};


int main()
{
    AnimationTrack<float> test1(
    {
        { 0.2f, 1.0f },
        { 0.5f, 2.0f },
        { 0.9f, 3.0f }
    });

    AnimationTrack<int> test2(
    {
        { 0.2f, 1 },
        { 0.5f, 2 },
        { 0.9f, 3 }
    });

    Animation<float, int> anim(test1, test2);
    auto track0 = anim.GetTrack<0>();
    auto track1 = anim.GetTrack<1>();
}
```

This example works fine in this use case, but what if I wanted to keep two tracks of the same type? With my current code both tracks would grab from the same static storage when calling `GetTrack`, but the problem is I can't figure out a way to make it work with repeats of the same type. Any suggestions?

Edit: Solution code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <array>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <map>

// Helper functions because C++11 doesn't have integer_sequence
namespace details
{
    template<typename T, T... Ints>
    struct integer_sequence
    {
        typedef T value_type;
        static constexpr std::size_t size() { return sizeof...(Ints); }
    };

    template<std::size_t... Ints>
    using index_sequence = integer_sequence<std::size_t, Ints...>;

    template<typename T, std::size_t N, T... Is>
    struct make_integer_sequence : make_integer_sequence<T, N - 1, N - 1, Is...> {};

    template<typename T, T... Is>
    struct make_integer_sequence<T, 0, Is...> : integer_sequence<T, Is...> {};

    template<std::size_t N>
    using make_index_sequence = make_integer_sequence<std::size_t, N>;

    template<typename... T>
    using index_sequence_for = make_index_sequence<sizeof...(T)>;
}

template<typename T>
struct AnimationTrack
{
    using map_type = std::map<float, T>;
    map_type keyframes;

    AnimationTrack(std::initializer_list<typename map_type::value_type>&& keyframes) :
        keyframes(std::move(keyframes)){}
};

template<typename T>
struct AnimationTrackView
{
    AnimationTrack<T>* track;

    AnimationTrackView() : 
        track(nullptr) {}

    AnimationTrackView(AnimationTrack<T>* track) :
        track(track) {}
};

template<typename... TrackTs>
class Animation
{
public:
    Animation(AnimationTrack<TrackTs>&... tracks)
    {
        StoreViews(details::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(TrackTs)>(), tracks...);
    }

    template<std::size_t Index>
    auto& GetTrack()
    {
        auto storage = GetStorage<std::tuple_element<Index, std::tuple<TrackTs...>>::type, Index>();
        return *storage[this].track;
    }

private:
    template<typename T, std::size_t Index>
    static auto& GetStorage()
    {
        static std::unordered_map<Animation*, AnimationTrackView<T>> storage;
        return storage;
    }

    template<std::size_t... Indices, typename... Ts>
    void StoreViews(details::index_sequence<Indices...> sequence, AnimationTrack<Ts>&... rest)
    {
        using expander = int[];
        (void)expander {
            0, (void(GetStorage<Ts, Indices>().emplace(this, std::addressof(rest))), 0)...
        };
    }
};


int main()
{
    AnimationTrack<float> test1(
    {
        { 0.2f, 1.0f },
        { 0.5f, 2.0f },
        { 0.9f, 3.0f }
    });

    AnimationTrack<float> test2(
    {
        { 0.2f, 9.0f },
        { 0.5f, 8.0f },
        { 0.9f, 7.0f }
    });
    
    Animation<float, float> anim(test1, test2);
    auto track0 = anim.GetTrack<0>();
    auto track1 = anim.GetTrack<1>();
}
```

Comment: @SamVarshavchik That is a valid criticism, I removed everything that isn't needed and kept it minimal.

Comment: Suppose that this is now a done deal. ***Now what***? How do you decide which instance the rest of the code should use, any time it wants a "track"? There can be only two answers: this is known at compile time, or this is only determined at runtime. If at runtime, templates can't help you, they are resolved at compile time. If at compile time then this simply becomes a matter of specifying an additional template parameter that resolves to a distinct template instance. Mission accomplished.

Comment: Perhaps you can answer your own question if you only move one step forward, and write down exactly how you intend to access the appropriate instance of each track of the given type. Given that, it should be possible to work your way backward, and make it so.

Comment: For the exact question, the answer is simple: use non-static `std::tuple<AnimationTrackView<TrackTs>...>` to store tracks. But as Sam Varshavchik pointed out, all this template machinery binds track types and numbers at compile time, which is far from “flexible”.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik It's going to be done at compile time everytime so I was wondering if there was a way to keep track of how many occurrences of the type are in the track tuple and use that to index somehow into the static storage for that certain occurrence of the type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably simpler than you anticipated. Just add a 2nd template parameter to `getStorage()`, `Index`, and simply forward it from `getTrack()`:

```
    template<std::size_t Index>
    auto& GetTrack()
    {
        return GetStorage<std::tuple_element<Index, std::tuple<TrackTs...>>::type,
                          Index>()[this].track;
    }

    template<typename T, std::size_t Index>
    static auto& GetStorage()
    {
        static std::unordered_map<Animation*, AnimationTrackView<T>> storage;
        return storage;
    }
```

Let's just say, for a lack of imagination, that `TrackTs...` is `<int, float, int>`.

`GetTrack<0>` and `GetTrack<2>` will now call `GetStorage<int, 0>` and `GetStorage<int, 2>`. They will be distinct template instances, each with its own distinct `static` storage instance.

It is not necessary to, somehow, in this instance, to renumber the additional template parameter so this becomes `<int, 0>`, and `<int, 1>`. This doesn't accomplish anything practical. Hijacking the original index into the tuple will accomplish, effectively, the same thing.

Comment: How would I then change the usage of GetStorage in for example StoreViews though?

Comment: Look up `std::index_sequence` in C++ reference. This produces, at compile time, a parameter pack of `<0, 1, 2...>` which can be slotted in the same way. This will require a little bit of rework, of that function, but should be possible (there need to be a wrapper function that produces the index sequence, then a specialization used to pull out the indexes). I would suggest for you to set this code aside and then attempt to practice, separately, implementing a logically-equivalent function. Once you have a working, much simpler, example, it'll sink in.

Comment: Alright, thank you for the clarification! I will take this as an answer as this definitely seems like the way to go.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence